# Real life examples of xvalues, glvalues, and prvalues?

Tags: c++, c++11

I was wondering if anyone could tell or explain some real life examples of xvalues, glvalues, and prvalues?. I have read a similar question :

[What are rvalues, lvalues, xvalues, glvalues, and prvalues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/what-are-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-and-prvalues)

but I did not understand what everyone meant. Can anyone explain in what cases these values are important and when one should use them?

Comment: hehe , what i meant was practical examples

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Consider the following class:

```
class Foo
{
    std::string name;

public:

    Foo(std::string some_name) : name(std::move(some_name))
    {
    }

    std::string& original_name()
    {
        return name;
    }

    std::string copy_of_name() const
    {
        return name;
    }
};
```

The expression `some_foo.copy_of_name()` is a **prvalue**, because `copy_of_name` *returns an object* (`std::string`), not a reference. Every prvalue is also an rvalue. (Rvalues are more general.)

The expression `some_foo.original_name()` is an **lvalue**, because `original_name` *returns an lvalue reference* (`std::string&`). Every lvalue is also a glvalue. (Glvalues are more general.)

The expression `std::move(some_name)` is an **xvalue**, because `std::move` *returns an rvalue reference* (`std::string&&`). Every xvalue is also both a glvalue and an rvalue.

---

Note that **names** for objects and references are always lvalues:

```
std::string a;
std::string& b;
std::string&& c;
```

Given the above declarations, the expressions `a`, `b` and `c` are lvalues.

Comment: Can you explain when should be rvalue reference should be used?

Comment: @M3taSpl0it: Move constructors and move assignment operators have rvalue reference parameters. Apart from that, there's little use for them. Most of the time, they are buried deep inside library code, and your own code need not bother with rvalue references.

Comment: You're missing a fundamentally important example. A function that returns a cv-qualified reference: `std::string const& reference_of_name() const`. This would be a prvalue, right?

Comment: cppreference article describes that lvalues are non-temporaries, and prvalues are temporary. Can you emphasize on this?